# iOS over the air install with manifest in install page

Tags: html, ios, installation, plist

I have an install page (for an iOS app over the air), with an itms link to the plist file.
(long story but) the plist file 'has to be' in the install page… I tried a data url:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=data:text/xml,<the-plist-content>">Download</a>
```

but that didn't work… What did I do wrong, or is there another way?

P.S.: the IPA url in the plist file has to be in its original state, not encoded!

Comment: Why can't the plist be a file in the web root?

Comment: @ElJay because the ipa url in it has to be able to change… (with javascript or something else)

Comment: Why can't the file be modified dynamically with server side scripting?

Comment: Well.. I tried to make this work offline, but ill do php...

Answer (score 0):

Is there any error in your OTA link, the argument of url needs to the url of the plist. Is that correct in your case?

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://www.yourdomain.com/Installer/Application.plist">Application Name</a>
```

Comment: My problem is the the plist file content can't be an external file… That's why i wanted to put it in the install page itself…

Comment: @eds1999 Sorry for the trouble, this is the only way that I have used to distribute In-House apps by OTA.  The plist contains the meta data to locate the actual ipa file,I would also like to know if there are any other ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The url path of the .plist file should be [https], not [http]. Maybe HTTP is not secure; make sure your .plist file is placed in a HTTPS-supporting server.